# How to edit or modify already created shipment?

Tags: magento-1.9, shipment

I am using Magento 1.9.3

I have created shipment against an order. Is there any way to update my created order shipment.

For example : Lets say I have created a shipment with 5 items. Now instead of delivery 5 items I want to deliver only 3 item. Remain items will be delivered in different shipment.

Here I need to edit my shipment, how I can do that?

Answer (score 0):

It's not Out of box in magento. For this we have to customize. It's very crucial to override the base functionality for this.

Can you please check the below paid Extension link.

http://magemart.com/all-magento/order-editor.html#